# Issues with deleting cookie in Django

Tags: python, django, cookies

I am having an issue deleting a HubSpot cookie in Django. I have a landing page with a form, and we were at a Trade Show capturing leads and since all leads used my computer and the `hubspotutk` cookie tracking user id was added, all new leads coming in were 'reconversions' instead of new contacts.

I am attempting to simply delete the `COOKIE` on page load if it is there so the `hubspotutk` cookie gets reset on every refresh of the page, but it appears the cookie is never actually removed although it is there.

Unfortunately with the code below I get an infinite redirect, only assuming that the `hubspotutk` cookie is not deleted as expected. Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

```
def request_demo_landing(request):

    if request.COOKIES.get('hubspotutk'):
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('site.com/request-demo-landing/')
        response.delete_cookie('hubspotutk')
        return response

    ...
```

I have also tried just updating the value to something random with Faker and that also doesn't work, it provides 2 keys that are the same in the dev console.

```
faker = Faker()
response.set_cookie(key='hubspotutk', value=f'{faker.numerify("###############")}')
return response
```

Comment: I believe deleting a cookie this way it still remains in browser.

Comment: As @WMRamadan has stated, you are simply not including a hubspot cookie in your response. To remove it from the client you would need to overwrite it or set its expiry to 0. You may be setting the `hubspotutk` cookie for two separate domains which would explain why it appears twice